# How to change template names in django listview according to url request?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 templates to render **one** listview and I am choosing the template according to the request url given by the user. I know that, I can add 2 classes for 2 templates on 2 seperate urls respectively. For example

```
class MyListView1(generic.ListView):
     template_name = 'myapp/list_one.html'
     .....
     .....

class MyListView2(generic.ListView):
     template_name = 'myapp/list_two.html'
     .....
     .....
```

But is there a way if I could check the url request inside one class and render the template according to it inside one listview class ? something like

```
class MyListView(generic.ListView):

   if request.path == '/list1'
         template_name = 'myapp/list_one.html'
   if request.path == '/list2'
         template_name = 'myapp/list_two.html'
```

I know this is not a valid code but just to visualise

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you want to do something dynamic in a generic view, it needs to be in a method. [This page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) shows the methods available for ListViews, and you can see that it includes [`get_template_names()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) which should do exactly what you want.

An alternative though would be to have two separate view classes, each defining their own template name, that inherit from a common base class which defines the rest of the shared functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass template from urls.py like

```
path("/list1",views.MyListView.as_view(template_name="myapp/list_one.html"),name="list1")
path("/list2",views.MyListView.as_view(template_name="myapp/list_two.html"),name="list2")
```